# A question about the property of echarts graphic

Tags: reactjs, echarts

Please help me, this is the ring diagram of echarts. I added a background diagram with the graphic attribute. Now it is aligned at the resolution of 1920*1080,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKLqZ.png)

but this project needs adaptation. I used "transform" to adapt, and then when the resolution becomes, for example, 2560*1080，it will become the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsCHf.png)

Here's my code. I want to know what I should do to make my ring diagram always in the center of the background diagram.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vvk8.png)

I tried to find the answer online in the past, but I didn't find any related questions. I hope I can get something here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.